# Marking packets going through OpenVPN tunnel and handling them differently at server side

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn, iptables

I'd need to create a client-server OpenVPN configuration such that at client side each IP packet is assigned some metadata (e.g. an id or name) and at the other side each of them is handled differently based on the metadata they're assigned with. For sending the metadata, I can think of two ways:

- Using ToS field, although it's small.
- Appending to payload and thereby changing length/checksum/...

Is there a better way in order to mark each packet? Does OpenVPN itself provide a solution for this requirement?

At the server side (i.e. OpenVPN server side), is there any way to leverage existing mechanism to kind of MITM each packet? To be more exact, I'd need to read each metadata (which each IP packet is coming with) and log some classification statistics or firewall them.

Does OpenVPN provide a clean solution for this? Otherwise should I touch OpenVPN server side code and build them by my own?

```
+------+   + ----+   +--------+           +--------+   +-----+    +----------+
| apps |---| tun |---| socket | ========= | socket |---| tun | ---| Internet |
+------+   +-----+   +--------+           +--------+   +-----+    +----------+
                   ^                                 ^
                   |                                 |
here packets are marked by my custom OpenVPN client  |
                                                     |
                        here I'd need to firewall packets based on the "metadata"
```

Comment: Please add an OS tag. E.g. on Linux, you'd use `iptables` or `tc` to manipulate packets and create statistics. This has nothing to do with a VPN or OpenVPN specifically. Also note that an easier way to add "metadata" is to use different IP source addresses (which is easy to do).

Comment: @dirkt Added Linux tag. You're right but my situation has all to do with OpenVPN. Is there any way for me to sit between OpenVPN deamon and its `tun` interface and intercept packets there? I mean. I'd need to filter some packets based on their "metadata" and decide which ones should be sent to `tun` and which ones shouldn't.

Comment: That's exactly what `iptables` is for. Google for tutorials, or add specific information about exactly you want to do (what kind of "metadata" to add from what source/conditions, what decisions to make on that "metadata").

Comment: @dirkt I do know `iptables` and situations it should be used for. However my situation is a little different. `iptables` can decide based on known TCP/IP or whatever characteristics, not my custom "metadata" embedded somewhere in IP packet. That metadata should be interpreted by me, `iptables` cannot handle it. So I'd need to put my firewall integration somewhere between OpenVPN listening UDP port  and its associated `tun`. To clear the problem, you can think of that "metadata" as the PID which OpenVPN client provides and embeds in IP packet.

Comment: What do you mean by *"handled differently"*? Different routing decisions, filtering, something else?

Comment: @sebasth Firewalling. Deciding which should be accepted and which should not. Please note that the decision is made absolutely based on the "metadata" my OpenVPN client provides, not by know TCP or UDP properties.

Comment: I repeat: Please describe exactly how your OpenVPN client "provides metadata", and exactly what decisions should be made based on it. You can easily match on *any* part of the packet (ToS, specific byte, extension header) using the `bpf` module of `iptables`.

Comment: @dirkt I tried to draw a figure to demonstrate the problem. "Metadata" could be process ID (PID) of client side's applications. This "metadata" is placed somewhere in IP packet (I haven't still decided where) and sent to the server side along with the IP packet itself. At the server side my own "code" should be executed for each incoming packet. My code queries some database for access control policies and finally decides should we let them in or not.

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto (Why) do you need more *"metadata"* to identify the source than the *source-ip:source-port*? Are you forwarding the traffic, if you are you probably should consider extending OpenVPN with your own logic instead trying to make the access control decisions elsewhere. If all the incoming traffic is to your app, then you should consider doing all the access control decisions there.

Comment: @sebasth It's a requirement for me to do firewalling at server side for each process running at client side. However using *source-ip:source-port* to distinguish processes is *not* an option for me as my "metadata" might change over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a custom OpenVPN client, you'll need to handle the marking in whatever way you decide to do it there, by writing the code. Note that the PID of the process that originated the packet is not available to the OpenVPN client, and in fact may not be available as a property of the packet at all. You'll need to put processes on the client in network namespaces or similar to obtain such information.

If you want other kinds of "metadata", please specify what you want.

On the server side, `iptables` can do everything you want without the need to modify the OpenVPN server. You can match on ToS with `--tos`, you can match on TTL with `--ttl-*`, you can match on any four bytes with `--u32`, or you can run a complete BPF filter program with `--bytecode` of you decide to add extensions headers or whatever. For matching packets, you can plunk them into desired egress interface, you can mark them internally and route them, or anything else you want. See `man iptables-extensions` for details.

So that part is easy, the difficult part is to find out what kind of metadata you want besides the PID in the first place, and then find some way to add them to the packets if the OpenVPN client doesn't really have a way to obtain this metadata.

**Edit**

For maximum flexibility, you can define your own [IP Option](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_IPDatagramOptionsandOptionFormat.htm) and add it to every IPv4 packet after the packet header. This will add noticably overhead, and may also cause more fragmentation (I don't know how OpenVPN handles the fragmentation inside the VPN tunnel).

In principle, you can also pass the packet back to userspace with the `NFQUEUE` target. If you do that for each packet, it will be glacially slow, so I strongly recommend against it.

If you really want to "run your own script" (I hope that's not a shell script) for each packet, the best thing would be to modify the OpenVPN server, too.

I still don't know the use case you have for this, but from your description so far of your plans, am fairly sure this is not going to work, because everything will slow down to a crawl. Please reconsider whatever you are trying to do, specify the use case (what do you want to achieve?), and figure out some solution in kernel space using `iptables`, and possibly multiple OpenVPN clients and servers if you want some segregation.

*Usually* you have classes of users/processes, where you want to allow some of them to do something, and handle others differently. Assign the users/processes to the classes, and handle the classes in kernel space. Don't try to handle the assignment to classes by adding this information to every packet.

Good luck, you are going to need it.

**Edit**

I should add that one usually thinks of the collection of all `iptables` rules both as the "scripting language" (rules in a chain are processed step by step, one can jump to other chains) and the "database" for most purposes. Of course, the "database" shouldn't be too big. If you want to change the "database", you add or delete rules in a chain made for that purpose.

Speed is important when handling packets (the kernel gets a *lot* of packets per second), and switching between the user space and kernel space is expensive in terms of speed. It's ok to do that once, as in the OpenVPN tun/tap interface, which has its own buffer, but more than once shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Does `iptables` allow me to run my own script to make the decision for each IP packet? Actually in the script I should be able to read whatever I need from the packet and query some database and finally inform `iptables` of my decision for the currently being passed IP packet.

Answer (score 1):

[SELinux Labeled Networking](https://selinuxproject.org/page/NB_Networking) allows you to write a policy labeling traffic all the way to the process generating it. The policy at the remote host does access decisions/filtering based on the labeling.  However Labeled Networking is only supported on Labeled IPSec and CIPSO, not directly on OpenVPN.

If you are forwarding the traffic, you probably should consider extending OpenVPN with your own logic instead trying to make the access control decisions elsewhere. If all the incoming traffic is to your app, you should consider doing all the access control decisions there instead.